# Populate a Chosen select list from a view

Tags: views

We have a request from a client to create an interface where they select nodes in a [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#selected-and-disabled-support) box. We have the Chosen module on the site and have successfully implemented features with it.

In this case, they want to have an admin interface where they choose which nodes populate a javascript image slider. I thought to simply make them a custom view where they can check a checkbox field to indicate whether to include the node or not. However, because they want the Chosen functionality, I need to populate a select box with the values from a view.

How can I create a select box that's populated by values from a view I've already defined? I've done some searching and found the [Entity Reference View Widget module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget), but that doesn't seem to do what I am looking for.

**Edit** I'm not so concerned about the Chosen functionality, I can handle that. What I really want to know is how to get the values from a view to populate a select box, either with a widget, or defining a select box in an form array.

Comment: Did u try it by creating a custom module? And where are u creating that select box?

Comment: @GonzaloJarjury I haven't tried it by creating a custom module-- how would you do that? The select box is going in a regular form array.

Comment: your field type in content type is entity reference, is it right?

Comment: @zhilevan Actually I want to use the node id and the title.

Comment: @user1359 I don't understand what you want, I just concluded you want to have a view that one of view fields is list of (chosen) entities(node+[nid]) with specified order , is it right? I can't help you if you clear the subject for me.

Comment: I am not able to understand the requirements as well. And as per the answer provided below, looks like you want a select box with the (nid => title) value of all the results in the view. Where do you need this box? Somewhere near the exposed filters? What is the CTA for select box; as in what happens when a admin changes its value? Let's say if a admin, un-selects some node from the select box, should the node disappear from the view too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically invoke a view to retrieve data and process it as needed:

```
  // Example select form array
  $form['my_selectbox'] = array(
    '#title' => t('My Select Label'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#description' => t('My select label.'),
    '#options' => array(),
  );

  $view = views_get_view("my_view_machine_name");

  //use "default" for default display
  $view->set_display("my_view_display_machine_name"); 

  // @TODO: Alter any other view properties 
  // (e.g. exposed_input, offset, etc.) as needed

  // Pre execute & execute view query
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();

  // $view->result contains an array of row objects inside the view.
  // the properties will vary based on your view
  foreach ($view->result as $row) {
    $form['my_selectbox']['#options'][$row->nid] = $row->node_title;
  }
```

Comment: How do you actually loop through the rows to get the values from them? I want the option values of the select box to be the nid, and the content in the option tag to be the title.

Comment: There was no example code work with so it was intentionally vague. An example has given in the answer, but it will vary based on your view.

Comment: While this might answer the question, the functionality seems to be incomplete. What happens when a user changes the value of this select box? It might be out of scope for this question. But, it would be really helpful if some light is shed on that part too.

Comment: @AjitS it is out of the scope of this question.